# Create Object from String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I am trying to figure out how to convert a string to an object. The separators are the `|` characters. So essentially this:

```
var myString = "Name, Bob | Location, Washington | Pet, Dog";
```

Becomes:

```
var myObj = {
Name: "Bob",
Location: "Washington",
Pet: "Dog"
};
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Comment: Nothing built-in for that, so you'll have to write the code yourself. Shouldn't be too bad, just a couple of string split functions, and looping through the results to build your new object.

If you're having specific trouble in any of those steps, then you should ask those questions.

Comment: How so? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What is the problem?  First split on the pipe to get the "<name>, <value>" combination and then split on the comma to get "<name>" and " <value>" ... and trim the leading space on the value ... and then add it to an object.

Comment: I figured it would come down to a loop and splitting. Wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way first.

Comment: @BryceHanscomb - the string was, but the Q was edited to fix it.

Comment: Did it really deserve -1?

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I was asking the OP to ask a more specific question and giving an example of the basic parts to help them narrow it down to a better question.

Comment: @mwilson - yes, it did (though it wasn't me) - your question showed no research which is one of the criteria for a -1.

Comment: I don't see how that question could be any more specific.

Comment: I would also ask this: Why is your data in this [awful] format to begin with?

Comment: You want some screen shots of me googling it or something?

Comment: To clear up any 'why do you have it this way' questions, this is the requirement that was given to me and I have to work with it. I don't know why I would ask for a string that's formatted as such when it's just going to end up as an object anyways. I'm sure the scenario has come up at some point in this worlds time, but I can't put a use case behind it as of right now. This is more than likely why nothing showed up when I researched how to do it thus having to post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, assuming the string is well formatted (You will need to [SHIM forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) in old browsers, or replace it with a loop):

```
var myString = "Name, Bob | Location, Washington | Pet, Dog";

var myObj = function(){
  var result = {};
  myString.split(/\s*\|\s*/).forEach(function(el){ 
    var parts = el.split(/\s*,\s*/); result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  });
  return result;
}();
```

Comment: @mwilson You're welcome. By the way, have you considered representing your object using JSON?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, my own personal requirement (at the time being) is to avoid using JSON or JQuery until I completely understand  JavaScript (to an extent). I appreciate your help!

Comment: @mwilson: JSON *is* JavaScript, so don’t worry about that. If you’re interested in learning about string manipulation, there are more interesting projects to pick than custom formats…

Comment: Thanks for that. I was under the impression is was something along the lines of JQuery. Unfortunately this particular question is asked by a professor (no I'm not cheating by posting this. We are allowed to use any means necessary for help since that's how it would be in real world). This one however, was a little weird and couldn't even figure out how to approach it.

Comment: @mwilson JSON is a subset of Javascript, used to describe objects and arrays in a string. For example: `var myObj = {"x": 5};` is a Javascript object, but `var myString = "{\"x\": 5}";` is a JSON representation of `myObj`, and to parse it is as simple as `var mySecondObj = JSON.parse(myString);`.