# Split an array of strings with each string containing more than one space

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings like this. Both left and right portions in the string are separated with spaces (More than 1 space for each).

```
const arr = [
  'A1789   Other tuberculosis of nervous system',
  'A179    Tuberculosis of nervous system, unspecified',
  'A1801   Tuberculosis of spine'
];
```

I need to turn this into an array of objects like this, with the first portion as the key and the second portion as the value of the key.

```
const arrOfObj = [
  { A1789: 'Other tuberculosis of nervous system' },
  { A179: 'Tuberculosis of nervous system, unspecified' },
  { A1801: 'Tuberculosis of spine' }
];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review the "how to ask a good question" guide, specially the section about posting your code (also called a minimum, reproducible example)

Comment: I think you should take example on something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346710/create-object-from-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I would split by space, assuming your key cannot contain space. So we'll have first item your key and the "rest" your value, which we can trim

```js
arr.map(s => {
  const [key, ...value] = s.split(" ");
  return { [key]: value.join(" ").trim() }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think something like this would work:

```js
const arrOfObj = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
    const match = str.match(/^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+(.+)/);
    arrOfObj[match[1]] = match[2];
});
```